# Асинхронное выполнение функции с помощью asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

```
def parse_and_send_message(message):
    pass

x = threading.Thread(target=parse_and_send_message, args=("HELLO!"))
x.start()
```

Как перевести данный код с использованием **asyncio** ?

Сама функция `parse_and_send_message` ничего не должна возвращать, внутри обработчик, который нужно выполнить в отдельном потоке, тк процесс занимает несколько секунд.

Comment: а что собственно должно распаралеллится? ведь указывая async, указываете await. но где, если у вас `pass`?

Comment: @finally вы бы не могли привести пример?

Comment: Вы не пробовали почитать документацию перед тем, как задать вопрос? В любом тюториале написано про async def и asyncio.run

Comment: @PakUula конечно пробовал, но Thread реализация кажется значительно проще. Возможно я чего-то понять не могу, поэтому и создан данный вопрос

Comment: @finally для понимания содержания функции обновил вопрос

Comment: @gohxr, во многих случаях функции обработчики выглядят так: чего-то ждёт, быстро обрабатывает, снова ждёт. Их можно засунуть в отдельные потоки, но это дорого по ресурсам. Асинхронное выполнение предназначено для выполнения нескольких таких функций в одном потоке, ведь вероятность того, что больше одного обработчика проснутся одновременно, мала. Если же у вас тяжеловесная функция, которая всерьез занимает процессор, asyncio не для вас. Выделяйте в отдельный thread и пусть работает сколько нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import threading, asyncio, random, time

def print2(message, n, sleep=False):
    if sleep: time.sleep(random.randint(50, 90) / 100)
    print(f'{n} {message} {threading.current_thread()}')

async def msg(message, n):
    for nn in range(n):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(1, 30)/100)
        print2(message, nn, sleep=False)

async def main(n):
    await asyncio.gather(msg("HELLO-A", n), msg("HELLO-B", n),)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for nn in range(10):
        threading.Thread(target=print2, args=["HELLO-T", nn], kwargs=dict(sleep=True)).start()
    asyncio.run(main(10))
```

out:

```
0 HELLO-A <_MainThread(MainThread, started 12400)>
1 HELLO-A <_MainThread(MainThread, started 12400)>
2 HELLO-A <_MainThread(MainThread, started 12400)>
0 HELLO-B <_MainThread(MainThread, started 12400)>
8 HELLO-T <Thread(Thread-9, started 5260)>
3 HELLO-A <_MainThread(MainThread, started 12400)>
0 HELLO-T <Thread(Thread-1, started 16608)>
3 HELLO-T <Thread(Thread-4, started 14520)>
5 HELLO-T <Thread(Thread-6, started 4452)>
2 HELLO-T <Thread(Thread-3, started 14544)>
9 HELLO-T <Thread(Thread-10, started 10820)>
1 HELLO-B <_MainThread(MainThread, started 12400)>
...
```