# Как запустить повторяющуюся блокирующую функцию в разных threads с помощью asyncio, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio, concurrency, threading

Есть блокирующая функция, для примера возьмем:

```
def blockme(n):
    x = random.random() * 2.0
    time.sleep(x)
    return n, x
```

(На самом деле мне нужны реквесты по API, но в контексте данного вопроса это не важно)

Мне надо запускать эту функцию в бесконечном цикле, причем каждый следующий запуск не должен дожидаться окончания работы предыдущих.

Как это сделать с помощью модуля `threading` я, в общих чертах, понимаю.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        threading.Thread(target=blockme, args=(i,)).start()
```

Но у меня возникли вопросы, которые скорее носят исследовательский характер нежели практический:

1. как это сделать с помощью `asyncio`, так как `asyncio` также поддерживает треды и прочие `concurrent.futures`
2. что не менее важно, а стоит ли это делать с помощью `asyncio`? Что даст `asyncio`? Простоту синтаксиса? Более читаемый код?
3. а вообще это возможно?

Я уже [задал этот вопрос на Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75185236/running-blocking-function-f-e-requests-concurrently-but-asynchronous-with-pyt/75192469?noredirect=1#comment132708187_75192469), правда с момента, как я его задал я уже получил ряд промежуточных знаний и поэтому вопрос модифицировался и отличается от оригинального. На данный момент, обсуждение на SO.com продолжается, задача не решена, но я получил следующую проблему. Один из участников предложил решение:

```
import asyncio
import random
import time

def blockme(n):
    x = random.random() * 2.0
    time.sleep(x)
    return n, x

def cb(fut):
    print("Result", fut.result())
    
async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futs = []
    for n in range(20):
        fut = loop.run_in_executor(None, blockme, n)
        fut.add_done_callback(cb)
        futs.append(fut)
    await asyncio.gather(*futs)
    # await asyncio.sleep(10)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Тут он еще добавил футуры, подразумевая, что нам еще нужны результаты работы (для моей задачи это не обязательно, если ваше решение будет без футур - мне тоже подойдет). И в таком виде, как он написал - все как-будто работает. Но тут есть нюанс: он утверждает, что если заменить `for n in range(20)` на `while True`, то все тоже будет работать, но у меня так не работает. Код что-то начинает делать в бесконечном цикле, но никакого вывода результатов не происходит. У меня есть подозрение, что то, что лежит в теле цикла не запускает функцию, а лишь определяет и собирает футуры в список. И без `await asyncio.gather(*futs)` работать не будет, а значит,  задачу не решает, так как бесконечный цикл невозможен.

Так что есть еще вопросы:

1. А у вас этот код работает, если заменить ограниченый цикл на бесконечный?
2. Если - "да", то есть варианты почему он не работает у меня? Проблема в окружении (версии модулей, настройки ОС и т.д.)?

PS.
На русском SO я нашел еще [вот такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1087335/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-asyncio), он похож, но во-первых, нет речи про бесконечный цикл, а, во-вторых, предложенное решение, все равно использовало `threading` в явном виде и коллеги критиковали использование `asyncio`, но одно дело - критиковать, а другое - можно ли это в принципе сделать.

Comment: А зачем вам все таки треды. У вас API что делает ? случайно не запросы по сети ? Если да, то вот тут как раз asyncio и нужен, так как позволяет делать сетевые вызовы параллельно, без создания тредов, что расходует на порядок меньше ресурсов. Вам главное найти библиотеку, которая сможет вызвать ваше API асинхронно (например aiohttp, если это API доступно по http)

Comment: А если API не может быть асинхронным и таки требует тредов, то зачем asyncio, опять же получаем дополнительные накладные расходы пытаясь обернуть треды в asyncio. Есть только один кейс когда вам нужны и треды и asyncio одновременно - когда у вас есть определенный набор потенциально асинхронных  операций и при этом есть другой вид операций, которые не асинхронные и будут долго блокировать поток

Comment: Поясню подробнее. (Возможно, одного камента не хватит). Вы правы - API шлет по http реквесты. Нужда в конкурентном запуске возникла , так как каждый эндпоинт отрабатывает очень долго. И если я запускаю реквесты в одном потоке один за другим, я теряю часть данных из-за больших промежутков между запросом-ответом-запросом-ответом... Значит, надо избежать ожидания ответа и запускать следующий реквест не дожидаясь ответа предыдущего(-их). Так и пришел к многопотоковости... Встал вопрос выбора инструмента для реализации многопотоковости и вот я тут.

Comment: И, по-хорошему, я это понимаю, мне надо изучить `aiohttp`, но нюанс был в том, что для этого сервиса, которы я опрашиваю реквестами, написан прекрасный, очень удобный SDK, который все реквесты прячет под капотом, а мне оставляет только классы и методы. И мне хотелось избежать ковыряния с запросами, обработки исключений (все это делает SDK), поэтому я стал воспринимать эти реквесты как блокирующие методы, отсюда и подход к решению.

Comment: asyncio предназначен в первую очередь именно для неблокирующих операций. Его основа это неблокирующие сетевые вызовы со стороны ядра ОС (вызовы select/poll/epoll), когда вы отправляете запрос по сети и ядро тут же возвращает управление вашему потоку и он может делать другую работу, периодически спрашивая у ядра не завершился ли вызов. asyncio оборачивает это в красивую оболочку с async/await. И это гораздо эффективнее (по использованию CPU), чем делать треды. Но эффект есть когда дело именно с aiohttp. А с тредами - это не больше чем синтаксический сахар и довольно спорный

Comment: P.S. запускать сразу все в работу параллельно плохая идея. Во первых при большом количестве тредов львиная доля ресурсов тратится на их переключение, во вторых другая сторона к которой вы обращаетесь так же получает гораздо бОльшую нагрузку. Стоит ограничивать кол-во параллельных обращений. И пулы соединений отлично решают это, хоть с asyncio, хоть без. Искать по "python пул потоков", вот один из первых примеров https://habr.com/ru/post/229767/

Comment: @Mike Спасибо за все разъяснения! Я получил массу информации к размышлению.

Comment: Если нашли решение, его нужно опубликовать в качестве ответа на вопрос, а не в вопросе. В вопросе должен быть только вопрос.

Comment: @insolor спасибо за комментарий, исправил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Футуры выполняются при вызове await другой функции или при выходе в другую асинхронную функцию.

`while True:` записывай как `while await asyncio.sleep(0, result=True):` и тогда треды будут запускаться на каждом круге.

Экзекутор нужно определить чтоб ограничить количество тредов. По умолчанию количество ядер умноженное на 5.

```
pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=40)

...

while  await asyncio.sleep(0, result=True):
    fut = loop.run_in_executor(pool, blockme, n)
    ....
```

Но при этом футуры будут всё ещё набиваться в очередь. Не знаю что стоит за причиной запускать бесконечное число потоков, но тут надо бы какой семафор поставить чтоб не забивать. Хотя бы тупой

```
if len(futs)>40:
   completed, futs = await asyncio.wait(futs, timeout=5)
```

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий и подробные разъяснения. Но код, который вы прислали не работает как ожидается. Выражение `while await asyncio.sleep(0)` не выполняется, точнее , видимо, условие не воспринимается как `True` и тело цикла обходится мимо. (Я поставил для теста `print(n)` после выхода из цикла: результат `0`)

Comment: @AlexeyTrukhanov да, поправил. можно перенести это внутрь цикла

Comment: Я уже вижу изменения, я решил по-другому - засунул `await asyncio.sleep(0)` внутрь цикла. Так работает. Вопрос - если мне не нужны футуры, я могу убрать присваивание  `fut =` оставил только `loop.run_in_executor(pool, blockme, n)` все остальные строки внутри цикла тоже убрал. Все работает. Так можно оставить чтобы избежать контроля списка футур?

Comment: `, result=True`

Comment: проблема этой спамилки в том что тредов в экзекуторе ограниченное число, а футур создается намного больше. эта программа убъёт атакующий комп быстрее чем атакуемый. если не складывать фут в массив, то их будет кушать GC: какие-то после выполнения, какие-то может до.

Comment: Доп. вопрос. Есть такой метод `asyncio.to_thread()`, который, на сколько я понимаю, использует `run_in_executor()`. Можно с помощью этого метода эту задачу решить? В догонку к вашему комментарию - и решить эту задачу без футур, чтобы избежать тех проблем, о которых вы пишете.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/asyncio/threads.py ну можно, но количество тредов не поправить

Comment: В общем, если без футур это решить нельзя, все же лучше использовать threading?

Comment: сделай бесконечный генератор ( тот что с yield). скорми его multiprocessing.dummy.Pool(40).imap_unordered() и это будет самая быстрая запускалка тредов. 40 можно увеличить до разумных пределов

Comment: Боюсь, изучение еще одной библиотеки еще больше отдалит меня от реализации всего проекта :)) Тем более, что мне не надо ни большое число тредов (я думаю, что для моих целей 3-4 это максимум, а то и 2 хватит) ни большой скорости, так как сам по себе эндпоинт очень медленный, а мне надо ускорить количество реквестов в секунду всего в два-три раза.

Comment: ну это стандортная)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за все разъяснения, многое стало понятно, а если и нет - то, по крайней мере, есть что изучать. У меня есть еще такая реализация того, что мне надо: я могу блокирующую функцию определить как асинхронную, внутри нее реквесты положить в бесконечный цикл и запустить 2-3-4 конкурентных исполнения с помощью `gather` или `TaskGroup`. Учитывая то, что компьютер, к которому предназначены реквесты по-умолчанию выдержит такой поток, нашему компьютеру ничего не грозит в таком случае?

Comment: Внимательно перечитываю ваши комментарии, нашел не до конца понятное место - я спросил: "если мне не нужны футуры, я могу убрать присваивание fut = оставил только loop.run_in_executor(pool, blockme, n)", вы ответили, что футуры все равно будут создаваться и заспамят комп. Уточню - они будут создаваться и заспамливать комп даже если изменить блокирующую функцию, чтобы она ничего не возвращала?

Comment: Еще момент. А если блокирующие функции будут отрабатывать быстрее, чем будут поступать на на них запросы (например, мы подберем нужный delay в asyncio.sleep()) b футуры не будут городиться в очередь, а им будет хватать времени выполняться - тогда проблем с заспамливанием компа не будет?

Comment: чтобы она ничего не возвращала - таких функций нет в питоне все возвращают. если присвоить значение в переменную то она проживет 1 цикл + время gc. если не присваивать, то она проживет до следующего gc. если положить её в массив то она проживет пока её из массива не вынуть. gc не предсказуем - так что нет 100% уверенности что все треды запустится.

Comment: выравнивать слипом можно скорость создания потоков, но это не надежное программирование
https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore тут просится

Comment: У меня периодически могут возникать подобные вопросы. Мы можем обменяться контактными данными (телеграм, воцап, скайп, любой вид связи), чтобы я мог задать вам вопрос напрямую? Я готов рассмотреть варианты с платной консультацией в любом удобном формате, если, конечно, вас это заинтересует.

Comment: Если в вопрос надо вникать, то он стоит 100$. А на простые вопросы ответ найдёте раньше, чем я прочитаю сформулированную мысль.

Comment: В любом случае, большое вам спасибо, что потратили на меня время! Если возникнет задача "в которую надо вникать", я думаю, смогу найти вас здесь.  Я добавил в свой вопрос внизу, окончательный код, который я сделал исходя из ваших замечаний. Пожалуйста, гляньте, если будет возможность - прокомментируйте. Что посоветуете посмотреть/почитать по вопросам, которые мы обсуждали? У меня, конечно, после ваших комментариев проясняется, но все равно остаются вопросы, хотел бы прояснить теорию.

Answer (score 0):

С определенными оговорками ответ выглядит так

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import FIRST_COMPLETED
import random
import time
import concurrent

def blockme(n):
    x = random.random() * 2.0
    time.sleep(x)
    return n, x

def cb(fut):
    print("Result", fut.result())

async def main():
    #Требуется контролировать количество потоков
    pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futs_set = set()
    n = 0

    #Требуется контролировать количество активных футур
    futures_limit = 40

    #Требуется контролировать частоту запуска блокирующих функций
    delay = 0.15

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        fut = loop.run_in_executor(pool, blockme, n)
        fut.add_done_callback(cb)
        futs_set.append(fut)

        #Требуется организовать логику, 
        #для того, чтобы футуры не копились бесконечно, например:
        if len(fut_set) >= futures_limit:
            completed, fut_set = await asyncio.wait(
                                       fut_set, 
                                       timeout=5, 
                                       return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED
                                       )

asyncio.run(main())
```